# Why can't I get internet explorer to work with this VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, runtime-error

A colleague gave me a file with this code working on its computer but not on mine. The purpose is to navigate and use a web page through internet explorer. It seems strange that this would work on his computer but not mine. However I cannot see any setting different between our computers.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetLTRTable()


SSOuserform.Show

Dim mySSO As String
Dim mypassword As String
mySSO = SSOuserform.MySSObox.Value
mypassword = SSOuserform.Mypasswordbox.Value
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://XXX/XXX/Query.asp"

While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend


ie.Document.all.Item("username").Value = mySSO
ie.Document.all.Item("password").Value = mypassword
ie.Document.all.Item("submitfrm").Click

While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend



Dim Fields As Object

Set Fields = ie.Document.all.Item("ADFields")
    Fields.Checked = True

Dim organization As Object

Set organization = ie.Document.all.Item("Org")
    organization.selectedindex = 0

Dim Modality As Object
    Set Modality = ie.Document.getElementsByname("Modality")(0)
        Modality.Value = "'XXX'"
Modality.getElementsBytagname("option").Item(102).Selected = "selected"
Modality.getElementsBytagname("option").Item(214).Selected = "selected"
Modality.getElementsBytagname("option").Item(222).Selected = "selected"




ie.Document.getElementsByname("CR1").Item(1).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("CR2").Item(6).Checked = True


ie.Document.getElementsByname("Action").Item(1).Click
While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Dim Startyear As Object
Set Startyear = ie.Document.getelementbyid("StartYR")
    Startyear.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("B3")
Dim Endweak As Object
Set Endweak = ie.Document.getelementbyid("EndFW")
    Endweak.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("B4")
Dim EndYear As Object
Set EndYear = ie.Document.getelementbyid("EndYR")
    EndYear.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("B5")

ie.Document.getElementsByname("Format").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ItemTotal").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld01").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld25").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld26").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld27").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld28").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld29").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld30").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld02").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld03").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld05").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld06").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld07").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld08").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld09").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld24").Item(0).Checked = True
ie.Document.getElementsByname("ADFld31").Item(0).Checked = True

ie.Document.getElementsByname("Action").Item(1).Click

End Sub
```

I have the "Run-time error '462' The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" when hitting the "While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend" line.

Comment: Check the internet security settings - are they set the same as for the other user?

Comment: Can you manually navigate (in I.E.) to the webpage?

Comment: Not sure which line of while...wend statement will show this issue? please try to debug it. Besides, here is [an article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-or-is-unavailable-error-462) and a [similar thread](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/178510/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs) about the 462 error, you could check it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers.
Security settings were indeed the problem. I unchecked "Enable Protected mode" for every zone and it worked.
Thank you so much!